# Навигация для страниц, подгружаемых во фрейм. XAML + C#

Tags: c#, xaml, навигация

Есть импровизированное меню, состоящее из нескольких пунктов. Под ним фрейм. По Тапу на пункте меню во фрейм подгружается соответствующая страница.
Для упрощения восприятия, приведу свой код только с двумя пунктами меню:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="Main_Menu">

        <StackPanel Tapped="MainMenu_Item_Tapped"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Tag="MainPage">

            <Image/>
            <TextBlock Text="MainPage"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Tapped="MainMenu_Item_Tapped"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Tag="SecondPage">

            <Image/>
            <TextBlock Text="SecondPage"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>    

    <Frame x:Name="Pages_Frame"/>
```

Событие на C#:

```
private void MainMenu_Item_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var navParams = "SomeParams";
    var page = (sender as StackPanel).Tag;

    Pages_Frame.Navigate(typeof(page), navParams);
}
```

Думаю, что как-то так должно это быть, но так не работает. 
Нужно или в `StackPanel.Tag` создать привязку, или напрямую воздействовать через *XAML* на `SourcePageType` для *Frame*.

Как это сделать, чтобы можно было передать `navParams`?
Может принято использовать какой-то другой путь для решения подобной задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

```
private void MainMenu_Item_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string pageName = (sender as StackPanel).Tag.ToString();
    Type page = Type.GetType("<Имя сборки>.Pages." + pageName);

    var navParams = "SomeParams";
    Pages_Frame.Navigate(page, navParams);
}
```

XAML код не менялся.